# Jboss 5.1 - Unable to start in Netbeans 7.3.1

Tags: java, netbeans, jboss

I m unable to start Jboss in Netbeans. It was working previously. Now, it stopped working after I deleted old project and created new project on netbeans.

The error Im getting is:

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:jar=EjbComponent.jar,name=LibrarySessionBean,service=EJB3" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.ejb3.common.registrar.spi.DuplicateBindException: Cannot install org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.factory.session.stateless.StatelessSessionRemoteProxyFactory@1709d5f under name "ProxyFactory/LibrarySessionBean/LibrarySessionBean/remote" as there is already an existing object there: org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.factory.session.stateless.StatelessSessionRemoteProxyFactory@502ca

Comment: Check if in the JBoss there are two ear running that share the same ejb with same name.

Comment: I guess yes, Can you please tell me how to delete this ear? I deleted all the projects and I still have the same error.

Comment: Thank you David, I deleted the ear file under Deploy folder of jboss server. This helped.